# PigLatin Translator Crashing C#

Tags: c#, crash

For some reason when I run this code I am noticing that the letter "I or i" or word "it" crashes the program. Also when I just click translate with nothing entered it crashes as well. I have gone over this code over and over but I can't find the problem. Any suggestions?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
       public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    private void btnTranslate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String input = Convert.ToString(txtInput.Text.Trim());
        String inputTr = Regex.Replace(input, " {2,}", " ");
        String pigLatin = "";
        String temp = "";
        String restOfWord = "";
        String vowels = "AEIOUaeiou";
        String consonants = "YBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVXWZbcdfghjklmnpqrstvxwzy";

        string[] words = inputTr.Split();
        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtInput.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Text must be entered");
            }

            int index = word.IndexOfAny(new char[] { 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' });

            if (Regex.IsMatch(word, "[@#$%0-9]"))
            {
                pigLatin += word + " ";
            }

            else if (!(char.IsPunctuation(word.Last())) && vowels.Contains(word[0]) && word.Contains(word.Substring(1, 2).ToLower()))

            {
                pigLatin += word + "way" + " ";
            }
            else if (char.IsPunctuation(word.Last()) && vowels.Contains(word[0]) && word.Contains(word.Substring(1, 2).ToLower()))

            {
                pigLatin += word.Substring(0, word.Length - 1) + "way" + word.Last() + " ";
            }
            else if (!(char.IsPunctuation(word.Last())) && consonants.Contains(word[0]) && word.StartsWith(word.Substring(0, 1).ToLower()))
            {
                string firstPart = word.Substring(0, index);
                restOfWord = word.Substring(index, word.Length - index);
                pigLatin += restOfWord + firstPart + "ay" + " ";
            }

            else if (char.IsPunctuation(word.Last()) && consonants.Contains(word[0]) && word.StartsWith(word.Substring(0, 1).ToLower()))
            {
                string firstPart = word.Substring(0, index);
                restOfWord = word.Substring(index, word.Length - index);
                pigLatin += restOfWord.Substring(0, restOfWord.Length - 1) + firstPart + "ay" + restOfWord.Last() + " ";
            }

            else if (!(char.IsPunctuation(word.Last())) && word.Contains(word.ToUpper()) && vowels.Contains(word.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper()))
            {

                pigLatin += word + "WAY" + " ";

            }
            else if (char.IsPunctuation(word.Last()) && word.Contains(word.ToUpper()) && vowels.Contains(word.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper()))
            {

                pigLatin += word.Substring(0, word.Length - 1) + "WAY" + word.Last() + " ";

            }
            else if (!(char.IsPunctuation(word.Last())) && word.StartsWith(word.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper()) && consonants.Contains(word.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper()) && word.Contains(word.Substring(1, 2).ToLower()))
            {
                string firstPart = word.Substring(0, index);
                restOfWord = word.Substring(index, word.Length - index);
                pigLatin += restOfWord.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + restOfWord.Substring(1, restOfWord.Length - 1).ToLower() + firstPart.ToLower() + "ay" + " ";
            }

            else if (char.IsPunctuation(word.Last()) && word.StartsWith(word.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper()) && consonants.Contains(word.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper()) && word.Contains(word.Substring(1, 2).ToLower()))
            {
                string firstPart = word.Substring(0, index);
                restOfWord = word.Substring(index, word.Length - index);
                temp = restOfWord.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + restOfWord.Substring(0, restOfWord.Length - 1).ToLower() + firstPart.ToLower() + "ay" + restOfWord.Last() + " ";
                temp = temp.Remove(0, 1);
                pigLatin += temp.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + temp.Substring(1, temp.Length - 1).ToLower() + " ";
            }

            else if (!(char.IsPunctuation(word.Last())) && word.Contains(word.ToUpper()) && consonants.Contains(word.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper()))
            {
                string firstPart = word.Substring(0, index);
                restOfWord = word.Substring(index, word.Length - index);
                pigLatin += restOfWord.ToUpper() + firstPart.ToUpper() + "AY" + " ";
            }

            else if (char.IsPunctuation(word.Last()) && word.Contains(word.ToUpper()) && consonants.Contains(word.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper()))
            {
                string firstPart = word.Substring(0, index);
                restOfWord = word.Substring(index, word.Length - index);
                pigLatin += restOfWord.Substring(0, restOfWord.Length - 1).ToUpper() + firstPart.ToUpper() + "AY" + word.Last() + " ";
            }
            txtOutput.Text = pigLatin;
        }

    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtInput.Text = "";
        txtOutput.Text = "";
        txtInput.Focus();
    }
    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void txtInput_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Crash = exception. You have to tell us which one and at which line.

Comment: What exception does it give? Got a call stack?

Comment: InvalidOperationException occurred 

Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Core.dll
@CallumBradbury

Comment: else if (!(char.IsPunctuation(word.Last())) && vowels.Contains(word[0]) && word.Contains(word.Substring(1, 2).ToLower()))

@Sinatr
its on that line of code that highlights

Comment: @KenYoung, you can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42783661/edit) your question to add required relevant details: **full** exception text (including message and call stack) as well as marking the line of code where it occurs (with e.g. comment say "// here").

Answer (score 1):

In several places throughout your code you have "Substring(1, 2)" - if the word you are currently processing is short than three characters long then you will get an exception because you are trying to get a substring that extends beyond the end of the string.

You need to add length checking into your code.
e.g.

```
...
...
else if (!(char.IsPunctuation(word.Last())) && vowels.Contains(word[0]) &&
&& (word.Length >= 3) && word.Contains(word.Substring(1, 2).ToLower()))
...
...
```

Just as a note on debugging - you could put a (conditional) breakpoint on the line where the exception occurs & then check each individual part of your if statement in the Immediate Window (copy & paste) to see which clause is causing the exception.

Comment: Plus the `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtInput.Text))` should be put at the beginning of the method, outside the `foreach`, plus the `txtOutput.Text = pigLatin;` should be put after the `foreach`...

Comment: @PaulF I have been messing with this for about 10 hours now... Can you help me with adding code for length checking? I understand what you mean with the substring though.

Comment: Sorry about the delay - I am not sure what you are trying to do with the check for the 2 character substring but the simple solution is just to insert (word.Length >= 3) in the if statement prior to trying to get the substring - see the edit above.